# Call REST GET Service from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, rest, get

I have a JSP that dynamically sets the page header of my application.

However, I want to be able to call the REST Service that gets user details based on the system user. I already have the system user value but need to call the backend service to get the details from the database. This is already implemented but I don't know how to setup the JSP to do this.

I do not want to use javascript as this is being used for the extjs side of things.

Comment: Is the question asking how to call REST WebService from the backend via JSP?

Comment: yes. I have a REST service implemented and need to call this in a JSP.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call REST from JSP, you could utilize [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). Once you have that you could walk through the [samples](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/) as well as the [HTTPClient Tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html). HTTPClient supports all REST API Call including GET/POST and others.

Check also [this following HTTPClient template](http://dyutiman.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/rest-template-using-apache-httpclient/) to see how HTTPClient can be used with REST. You need to call a similar code from your JSP.

In particular to REST GET Service, you want to look the following block from the template in the above link

```
final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 10000);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(SERVER_URL + url);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
```

Comment: So the above code would be in a new class and then this would be imported into the jsp so that it can be used within the jsp code?

Comment: Yes correct. Create a Utility class (you can call it RESTUtil) that you would use in your JSP for calling REST Based service. You could use the template in link I have given above to start with and continue by reading the API Doc of HTTPClient if you need additional parameters.

Comment: This, IMHO, is a terrible idea. JSPs are for presentation only - they should not be used for 'business logic' and they definitely should not be used for back-end services, like querying a database or making a web service call. Please find yourself a good web framework - there are several good ones out there, and any of them would be better than hacking up a JSP page to do this sort of thing.

Comment: A web framework like Spring MVC will be doing exactly what is proposed here.